# Ocelot and .Net framework web api

Tags: .net, api, ocelot, .net-4.8

I recently created a .net framework web api and not .net core due to reliance on old libraries.
Also, we had the requirement to have an api gateway, with this we used ocelot but it keeps on failing during startup with the error below.

**Unable to start Ocelot, errors are: When not using service discovery DownstreamHostAndPorts must be set and not empty or Ocelot cannot find your service!**

The gateway works if only .net core web apis are configured in the ocelot Routes, but when the .net framework api settings are added, it throws this error.

Is there anything specific to .net framework apis that I should do to make this work?